# Script for scanning with ClamAv

Tags: bash, scripts, shutdown, clamav

I am new to Linux and I want to have a script to run ClamAV on my entire system, write it to a log file, then shut down after it is done (since I will be running it before I go to bed). I already made it executable. This is what I have so far:

```
~!/bin/bash
sudo clamscan -r -i / > clamav.log
poweroff
```

Comment: AskUbuntu supports Ubuntu and official derivatives only. Mint is not one of them. In the future you may want to post your questions at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` not `~`. Instead of using `sudo` in scripts, run the script with `sudo`. ClamAV runs as a daemon and writes a log by default whenever it runs. You do not need to manually run it.

Comment: @Zanna Where is the log file located at?

Comment: Should be in `/var/log/clamav`

Comment: @Zanna So should the script just look like this?                                                        #!/bin/bash

clamscan -r --bell -i /

Comment: you don't need a script at all ;)

Comment: @Zanna Really? I thought I remember someone saying I need to manually run it. hmmm

Comment: Take a look in the logfile. If you see recent entries, it's running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [manual page of `clamscan(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/clamscan.1.html):

```
#!/bin/sh
clamscan -r -i --stdout / > /path/to/clamav.log
exec poweroff
```

Mark the script file with the above content as executable,

```
chmod +x scan-and-poweroff.sh
```

and execute it as super-user,

```
sudo scan-and-poweroff.sh
```